# boost::filesystem::space() is reporting wrong diskspace

Tags: c++, windows, boost, diskspace, boost-filesystem

I have 430 GB free on drive `C:`. But for this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path p("C:");

    std::size_t freeSpace = boost::filesystem::space(p).free;
    std::cout<<freeSpace << " Bytes" <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<freeSpace / (1 << 20) << " MB"<<std::endl;

    std::size_t availableSpace = boost::filesystem::space(p).available;
    std::cout << availableSpace << " Bytes" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << availableSpace / (1 << 20) << " MB"<<std::endl;

    std::size_t totalSpace = boost::filesystem::space(p).capacity;
    std::cout << totalSpace << " Bytes" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << totalSpace / (1 << 20) << " MB"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2542768128 Bytes
2424 MB
2542768128 Bytes
2424 MB
2830102528 Bytes
2698 MB
```

I need to know how much diskspace is available because my application has to download a huge file, and I need to know whether it's viable to download it.

I'm using mingw on Windows:

```
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.1.0
```

I also tried using MXE to cross compile from Linux:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ (GCC) 5.5.0
```

Both are returning the same numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::size_t` is not guaranteed to be the biggest standard unsigned type. Actually, it rarely is.

And `boost::filesystem` [defines `space_info` thus](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#space_info):

```
struct space_info  // returned by space function
{
  uintmax_t capacity;
  uintmax_t free; 
  uintmax_t available; // free space available to a non-privileged process
};
```

You would have easily avoided the error by using `auto`, which would be natural as the exact type is not of any importance. Nearly always only mismatch hurts, thus [Almost Always `auto`](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Answer (score 2):

Use a type that `boost::filesystem::space(p).free` requires. it may require a 64 bit integer type:

```
uintmax_t freeSpace = boost::filesystem::space(p).free;
```

use of `auto` is also good.